# How to send HTTPs request to an ELB in AWS to route it to HTTP port on the EC2 instances running behind it attached to auto scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

I’m trying to setup an Elastic Load balancer (listening to HTTPs on port 443) with EC2 instances running behind it (attached to an Auto-Scaling group).
I want to send HTTPs traffic to the ELB. However, I want the request to be translated as HTTP which would then be routed to the EC2s within the AutoScaling Group on port 80.

How is the translation of HTTPs to HTTP be done. Is any additional configuration required to achieve this. *(I read about SSL termination and wonder if it’s taken care of already)*
Please, let me know what I’m missing.

Answer (score 2):

1. create TLS using AWS Certificate manager
2. associate it to listener on ALB on port 443 and https
3. add another listener on port 80 and http and configure it to redirect like on the image below

[image]